# __info__/1 with :exports in Elixir 1.6

Tags: elixir

In Elixir 1.5 I used to use the `__info__` function with the `:exports` atom as the `kind` parameter.

In 1.6 `:exports` has been removed as an option.  I reviewed the changelog for 1.6 and didn't see any mention of the change.

```
# Used to work
MyModule.__info__(:exports)
```

What is the way to do it now?

---

1.5 docs: [https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.5.0/Module.html#**info**/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.5.0/Module.html#__info__/1)

1.6 docs: [https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.0/Module.html#**info**/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.0/Module.html#__info__/1)

Comment: [Where is `__info__/1` documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059471/where-is-info-1-documented)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MyModule.module_info(:exports)`, which is the Erlang variant. Smells like some cleanup of useless duplication got done here. The 1.5 docs explicitly referred to the Erlang module documentation (http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html) and all the functionality described there is still available through the Erlang variant of this call.