# Where is `__info__/1` documented?

Tags: elixir

Found this in [`Ecto.Repo.Supervisor`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.0.0/lib/ecto/repo/supervisor.ex) and I was wondering where the other options to `__info__/1` are documented:

```
  def compile_config(repo, opts) do
  # (...)
    behaviours =
      for {:behaviour, behaviours} <- adapter.__info__(:attributes),
          behaviour <- behaviours,
          do: behaviour

  # (...)
  end
```

[The `Module` documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.7.3/Module.html) only mentions that

> After a module is compiled, using many of the functions in this module
>   will raise errors, since it is out of their scope to inspect runtime
>   data. Most of the runtime data can be inspected via the `__info__/1`
>   function attached to each compiled module.

Comment: That's interesting. The `Module` page on hexdocs [had `__info__/1` documented](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.0/Module.html#__info__/1) in Elixir `1.6.X`, but it isn't there in the `1.7.X` and `master` docs (even though it's there in the source).

Comment: I assume that it has been omitted to discourage direct usage. Probably because it looks like OO inheritance than clean FP?

Comment: All methods starting with `__` are automatically omitted **unless** the @doc is explicitly specified, which in this case is.

Comment: So [`Module` docs for `1.6.6`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.6/Module.html#__info__/1) still has an entry for `__info__/1`, but it is missing starting with [`1.7.0-rc.0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.7.0-rc.0/Module.html#__info__/1).

Comment: Did a diff between tags `1.6.6` and `1.7.0-rc.0`, but other then finding a new supported atom (`:deprecated`), I didn't not see any changes that would exclude `__info__/1` from the docs. (Used commands in [How to compare two tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/how-to-compare-two-tags)) Isn't [`ex_doc`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc) used for generating documentation? It's an external library so maybe changes in there caused this?

Comment: Exactly, I believe something changed in ExDoc, not Elixir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182816/discussion-between-toraritte-and-sheharyar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in [`Module`'s source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.4/lib/elixir/lib/module.ex#L483):

```
 @doc """
  Provides runtime information about functions and macros defined by the
  module, etc.
  Each module gets an `__info__/1` function when it's compiled. The function
  takes one of the following atoms:
    * `:functions` - keyword list of public functions along with their arities
    * `:macros` - keyword list of public macros along with their arities
    * `:module` - the module atom name
    * `:md5` - the MD5 of the module
    * `:compile` - a list with compiler metadata
    * `:attributes` - a list with all persisted attributes
  """
  def __info__(kind)
```

#### Undocumented atoms

`:deprecated` - shows deprecated functions in a module that are prefixed with the `@deprecated` attribute (included in `1.7.0-rc.0`)

---

#### Test drive

Trying out the above `behaviour =` snippet above in a Phoenix project:

```
$ iex -S mix phx.server

iex(3)> Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.__info__(:attributes)
[
  vsn: [168581197275628950002173003256895919063],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Migration],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Queryable],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Schema],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Transaction],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Storage],
  behaviour: [Ecto.Adapter.Structure]
]

iex(4)> for {:behaviour, behaviours} <- 
...(4)>     Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.__info__(:attributes),
...(4)>   behaviour <- behaviours, 
...(4)>   do: behaviour
[Ecto.Adapter, Ecto.Adapter.Migration, Ecto.Adapter.Queryable,
 Ecto.Adapter.Schema, Ecto.Adapter.Transaction, Ecto.Adapter.Storage,
 Ecto.Adapter.Structure]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.8.0/Module.html) documentation has been updated to include [`__info__/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.8.0/Module.html#c:__info__/1) since 1.8.0.

See also a related [bug ticket](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/8376) (that might have been created because this question).